# FileHelpers .Net library Error - delimeter found after the last field of the class

Tags: filehelpers

Visual Studio 2019, .Net Core 2.2 - getting the following error when debugging code to parse a csv file with 10 rows, using the FileHelpers .Net library:

```
{"Line: 2 Column: 593. Delimiter ',' found after the last field 'Taxonomy_Group_15' (the file is wrong or you need to add a field to the record class)"}
```

I have checked the file and I don't see anything in column 593 (or anywhere else beyond the defined columns for that matter).

Here is the code I'm testing with:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var engine = new FileHelperEngine<Entity>();

            var result = engine.ReadFile(@"C:\Users\me\Desktop\pfile_20190902-20190908.csv");

                foreach (Entity subject in result)
                    {
                    Console.WriteLine("Subject Info:");
                    Console.WriteLine(subject.NPI + " - " + subject.Entity_Type_Code);
                    }
        }
```

The error is thrown before the foreach loop is entered. I've checked my Entity Class and all columns are present. Can someone help me understand what's going on here?

Comment: Hi, maybe there is a , in another field, and is unescaped, do you have any quoted field ? do you have a header line ? Thanks

Comment: @MarcosMeli Hi Marcos - it's great to hear from the source of this great library!  I can not see any issue with the csv having any extra characters.  Perhaps I'm missing something - the csv file can be found here: http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=96958684535974249701  It's only 20 rows.  If you have time to take a look at it to see if I'm missing something, I'd appreciate it, but I also understand if you can't.  Thanks!